# Would ldd print all the .so files that one uses when running?

Tags: linux, ldd

I once saw a binary (say xyz) on Linux, when it is running, i can see it loads a .so file (say abc.so), but when i run "#ldd xyz", the abc.so is not contained in the outputs of the ldd.

can anyone help to explain this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Ldd only displays shared libraries that are loaded in the program "bootstrap". A program can  use dlopen(3) to load other shared libraries at will, therefore ldd(1) and lsof(8) can show different lists of shared libraries loaded.